# Citrix web interface with pass-through authentication displays no applications

Tags: authentication, citrix, xenapp

I have a user who logs into our Citrix web interface with pass-through authentication.  When she connects to the web site, it displays a message saying that no published resources can be found, and indeed it displays no application icons.

But when I have her log out and log back in with explicit credentials, she gets her normal list of applications.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to "Pass Through Authentication" Citrix "lifts" the current windows credentials. So if the user is at home, logged as "maryscomputer/user" that means nothing to Citrix, and that user is assigned to no applications or resources like desktops when they log in. That's why explicit "domain\mary" pulls up applications, because that account has resources assigned.

So one of two things

1. Pass Through isn't working OR
2. It's passing through useless information